# Rewrite query string url in web.config in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, web.config-transform

I want to redirect url From
    http://example.com/page-name/?id=45 to http://example.com/page-name/45
in web.config in IIS.
How can I write it's rule for web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using below code

```
<rule name="Redirect to url" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^page-name/([^/]+)/?$" />
            </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="page-name/?id={R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

but I am getting 404 Error if I use this code. what is the problem in this code?

Comment: Try {R:1} instead of {R:0}