# Php: Rewrite URL using web.config

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

This my first PHP application, I am using both *.html* and *.php* pages in this website. If user browses *mysite.com/users/?abc123*, it successfully loads details of user with id '**abc123**' on plain html page *mysite.com/users/index.html* via Ajax. Now, I am tasked to remove `?` from the URL so that if user browses **mysite.com/users/abc123**, then **mysite.com/users/index.html?abc123** should serve the details successfully.

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27371859/369383) and added this rule to my web.config but that didn't seem to work and I received:

> Error: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

```
<rule name="Remove question mark" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^users/(.*)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="users/?{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

---

Please assist me with following concerns in mind:

1. I can only use web.config for URL rewriting (to keep things simple)
2. The page I want to rewrite URL for is .HTML not .PHP (if that matters)
3. I am testing my PHP site locally in IIS 8 configured to serve PHP

Comment: Do you have iis url rewrite installed? http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working

```
<rule name="Remove question mark" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^/?users/([^/]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/users/index.html?{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: This did not work, got same *HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found*, when browsed http://localhost:8080/users/abc123.

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks a lot. One small thing... will it work for /users as well as /users/ ? I mean do I need to add separate rules for both ?

Comment: By default it should be working because `/users` and `/users/` are the same and load by default `/users/index.html`